# Searching data from API with Laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, guzzle

I try to put Searching Feature on the page that showing table list in a database with API. But it keeps getting error, I don't know what to try anymore.

Here is my source code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

class PaymentDBController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    private $client; 

    public function __construct() {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'http://20.20.20.192:8585/api/v1/'
        ]);
    }
    public function index(Request $request) {

       $response = $this->client->request('GET', 'tables',[
            'query' => [
                'limit' => '100'
            ]
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true)['data'];
        return view('cobaTable', compact('data'));

         if ($request->has('search')) {
        $take = Client::table->when($search, function ($query, $search) {
            return $query->where('name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%");
        });
       } else {
        $take = Client::table::all();
       }
       }
```

Here is one of the error:

> Call to undefined method GuzzleHttp\Client::all()

I try both `Http` and `Guzzle` methods, but still getting errors
May someone has advices, please?

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Guzzle. Please use this type of coding

```
use GuzzleHttp;
private $response;

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$this->response= $client->request('GET', 'URL');
```

Comment: Thank You, sir. for that type i already success.
this one that i try to figure out is giving "searching" to those API get data ||

example : $this->response= $client->request('GET', '127.0.0.1:table');
i can search this table name list by Laravel-PHP search request